# ReadDirectoryChangesW issues

Tags: c++, c, winapi, asynchronous, readdirectorychangesw

I'am using  [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  to watch a directory changes asynchronously, based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150984/asynchronous-readdirectorychangesw-getqueuedcompletionstatus-always-times-out?rq=1) I implement a function that watch a given directory, but I still get the error message  `GetQueuedCompletionStatus(): Timeout`

```
void Filewatcher::OpenWatchDir(QString PathToOpen)
{

    QString path=QDir::fromNativeSeparators(PathToOpen);

    LPCTSTR  Dirname=(LPCTSTR)path.utf16();//.toStdWString().c_str();

    dirinfo_t* d =(dirinfo_t*) malloc(1*sizeof(dirinfo_t));
    d->CompletionKey = (ULONG_PTR)&somekey;
    dirinfo_init(d);

    /* set up */
    runthread = TRUE;
    d->hDirFH = CreateFile(Dirname,
                    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
                    FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                    NULL,
                    OPEN_EXISTING,
                    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                    NULL);

    d->hDirOPPort = CreateIoCompletionPort(d->hDirFH, NULL,
                          (ULONG_PTR)d->CompletionKey, 1);

    DWORD errorcode = 0;    // an error code
    BOOL bResultQ = FALSE;  // obvios=us
    BOOL bResultR = FALSE;
    DWORD NumBytes = 0;
    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION* pInfo = NULL; // the data incoming is a pointer
                                           // to this struct.
    int i = 0;

    while ( runthread )
        {
            bResultR = ReadDirectoryChangesW(d->hDirFH, (void*)d->buffer,
                                              16777216, TRUE,
                   FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME  | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION  ,
                                              NULL,
                                              &d->o->overlapped,
                                              NULL );
            bResultQ = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(d->hDirOPPort,
                                                 &NumBytes, &(d->CompletionKey),
                                                 (LPOVERLAPPED*)(d->o), 1000);
            if ( bResultQ && bResultR )
                    {
                wprintf(L"\n");
                pInfo = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*) d->buffer;
                wprintf(L"File %s", pInfo->FileName);
                wprintf(L" changes %d\n", pInfo->Action);

                qDebug()<<"file  "<<pInfo->FileName<<" was"<<pInfo->Action;
                memset(d->buffer, 0, 16777216);
            }
            else
                   {
                       errorcode = GetLastError();

                       if ( errorcode == WAIT_TIMEOUT )
                       {
                           qDebug()<<"GetQueuedCompletionStatus(): Timeout\n";
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           qDebug()<<"GetQueuedCompletionStatus(): Failed\n";
                           qDebug()<<"Error Code "<<errorcode;
                       }
                       Sleep(500);
                   }
               }


}
```

I need to know how use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` asynchronously with `IoCompletionPort`.

Any help please.

Comment: Perhaps the directory didn't change in that one second you passed as a timeout?

Comment: I change it to 10000 millsec I can see now my events, but my problem now is that I can't handle my application any more (the call wasn't in a separate thread), I thought that was the point of working with `ReadDirectoryChangesW` asynchronously.How can I seperate my application thread from watching directory thread?

Comment: oumaya: The point is that you can wait on the completion port and other objects at the same time, even GUI messages, using `(Msg)WaitForMultipleObjects(Ex)`.  So you can do other useful work while waiting for the completion port.

Comment: Well, in Qt, you have very little option but to run it in a separate thread. Normally, you would integrate the wait into your message pump, but there is no provision for that in Qt, unfortunately.

Comment: @avakar: So Qt has no equivalent to `XtAddAppInput`, to get new handles/file descriptors into the wait loop?  How did it ever gain a following when it doesn't support basic operations that both Win32 and Unix toolkits have had for decades?

Comment: @BenVoigt, well, if you find an equivalent, please do share.

Comment: @avakar: Found and added to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you guys for your answers, after a deep research and retesting code I solve my problem based on [this](http://sumatrapdf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/FileWatch.h) , I really appreciate your help.

Comment: why do you link to third party site?
now the link is dead

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to use a completion port here, simple overlapped I/O with an event will work fabulously.

The key is to wait for this operation (whether event or completion port) at the same time as all other events (possibly including GUI messages), and only check the status when the event becomes signaled.  For that, use `(Msg)WaitForMultipleObjects(Ex)`.

In Qt, you can add Win32 events (used by `OVERLAPPED` structure for async I/O) using `QWinEventNotifier` as described here:

- http://www.downtowndougbrown.com/2010/07/adding-windows-event-objects-to-a-qt-event-loop/

Comment: Note that `QWinEventNotifier` is missing from several recent versions of Qt. see http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/issues/detail?id=91

Comment: @avakar: No, it's not missing.  It just moved.  And in Qt 5 it moved again, to become a public API.  At least if that blog post can be believed.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, in fact am working with QT 4.7.4, so as the article posts I can use `QWinEventNotifier` legally. I will try to proceed like the author said   _make a new QThread subclass that does nothing except call the Windows WaitForSingleObject() function (or WaitForMultipleObjects() or any variants) in an infinite loop. Set it up so the call to the Windows function blocks until an event occurs, and emit a signal from the thread whenever something happens. Then you can connect that signal to a slot in your program_ I'am newbie so how to block it until an event occurs?